# Splice confusion

Tags: javascript

I've been going through the rot.js tutorial [located here](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Rot.js_tutorial,_part_1) and I'm making sense of the majority of the examples.

However, I'm confused by one line of code and I was hoping someone could explain what's going on.

This is in the `Game._generateBoxes` function toward the bottom of the page:

```
var key = freeCells.splice(index, 1)[0];
```

I understand that it's removing one element from location `index` from the `freeCells` array and assigning it to `key`. I don't understand what the `[0]` is doing at the end. I tried removing it and it appeared to function normally. What is this accomplishing?

Comment: freeCells.splice(index, 1) return an array so the [0] is for pointing to the first item of the returned array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var key = freeCells.splice(index, 1);
```

… assigns an array with one member to `key`.

```
var key = freeCells.splice(index, 1)[0];
```

… assigns the value of the member of the aforementioned array and then discards the array.

```js
var index = 1;

function one () {
  var freeCells = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  var key = freeCells.splice(index, 1)[0];
  alert(typeof key);
}

function two () {
  var freeCells = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  var key = freeCells.splice(index, 1);
  alert(typeof key);
}

one(); two();
```